# Secure MAC implies that probability of same tags on different messages is negligible

Tags: mac

So let any **secure** MAC (message authentication code) be given.

Intuitively, I think it is clear that the probability of getting the same tag on two *different* messages is very small, i.e. negligible. I want to prove this statement mathematically.

How can we

1. formulate this in an exact manner (because, negligible in *what*? I guess negligible in $|k|$, where $k$ is the chosen key - I am not sure about this)
2. (once we have a precise formulation) *prove* this statement?

Supposing that this probability is *not* negligible, we'll have to construct a PPT adversary $\mathcal A$ that, somehow, is able to "beat" the system (which would be in contradiction with the fact that the MAC is secure).

Comment: If you'll have to construct a PPT adversary, then you'll only be able to show this for $\hspace{1.25 in}$ _PPT-computable_ sequences of pairs of messages. $\:$

Comment: The term *neglible* usually refers to some security parameter (which often is the key length). The same term is used in the definition of "secure" for your MAC, which will give you the point of attack. (Also, welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange.)

Answer (score 2):

Is this a homework problem?

Here's a hint: Suppose that the probability of getting the same tag on two different messages is $p$.  Show how to construct an adversary that breaks the MAC (i.e., forges a valid tag), and that has success probability $p$.  Assuming the MAC is secure, what can you conclude about the possible range of values for $p$?

Comment: It's not a homework problem. By the way, I don't see the relevance of such a comment/question.

Comment: @Dorothy, because this looked a lot like a homework problem, because I'm not interested in solving other people's homework problems for them -- and because doing so would be a disservice to them, because the entire point of homework is to learn how to solve the question on your own, which you can't get by reading other people's solutions. You can read the [thread on meta](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/q/90/351). One suggestion: I would recommend revising the question to show what you've tried already and where you've gotten stuck. My answer should give you a good direction to try...